# Hydrogen bonding in concave rings

Tags: hydrogen-bond

Can hydrogen bonding occur if both O and H are in a ring having 6 members  however the ring is concave .
Example 
3 hydroxycyclohexanone

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work.  The ring geometry holds the carbonyl oxygen and hydroxyl hydrogen too far apart.  If you have a molecular model kit, construct the molecule with it and see what happens to the oxygen and hydrogen atoms.

Hydrogen bonding between *different* molecules is not constrained by the ring geometry, and thus works perfectly well.